# Ascending central series of $S_3$ x $D_4$

Tags: group-theory

Can anyone show me step by step how to compute the ascending central series of $S_3$ x $D_4$ please?

I am very confused about the definition of the central series which involves taking the preimage of the centre of a factor of the "canonical isomorphism" (I don't even know what is the isomorphism..)

Thanks very much

Comment: You should start by computing the centre of the group. Can you do that?

Comment: The center of the group has to be the product of the center of each of the components. So the center would be {e}x{e,r180}, where r180 is the rotation by 180 degrees.

Comment: OK, so $G/Z(G) = S_3 \times D_4/Z(D_4) \cong S_3 \times V$, where $V$ is a group of order $4$. Can you see what the centre of that group is?

Comment: V is the Klein-4 group and it is abelien, so the center of S_3 x V is {e} x V, which is isomorphic to just V

Comment: Yes, and the invrse image of that subgroup in $G$ is  $Z_2(G)$, which is equal to$\{ e \} \times D_4$. So $G/Z_2(G) \cong S_3$, which has trivial centre, and hence the upper central series becomes constant at $Z_2(G)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot
May I know how do I arrive at "Inverse image of the group is equal to {e} x $D_4$" ? The inverse image of what function? (the text says "the isomorphism", but what is it exactly?)